# Correct way to end response

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

So [Response.End()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) is harmful, how do I flush the response and terminate it? Is this the correct way:

```
resp.Flush();
resp.Close();
```

Comment: More information on the harm here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Actually, you don't need `resp.Flush()` - `Close()` will flush the response.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This doesn't actually terminate the thread though does it? Should I be doing:

resp.Close();
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();

Comment: Close also terminates the current thread (it throws an exception under the hood), so you don't need to abort the thread.