# Logs Filling Up With: An error occurred communication with the remote host

Tags: iis-7

We are trying to understand what is happening with this error, is this just users disconnecting from the site?

```
System.Web.HttpException  An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800703E3.  
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException  The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)  StackTrace:    
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)     
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()    
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)     
at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     
at System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c <InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)     
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)     
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()    
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)    
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()   
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()  
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this error comes up when the connection to the user is lost. They might have closed the browser or been disconnected (or the request [failed or was canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564892/54804)).

[The answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1556133/54804) recommends checking [Response.IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx) before calling Flush()

You [might not even need to explicitly call Flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6118977/54804)