# Problems with Response.TransmitFile, Response.End and IE

Tags: asp.net, response.transmitfile

I am developing an ASP.NET app which at one point sends a file to the user, using Response.TransmitFile.

It works fine on my dev machine, and when I deploy it to the test servers it still works on two of them; in one of the servers though (W2K3) it only works on Firefox, when I try it on IE7 I get an error like "Internet Explorer cannot open file sendfile.aspx on (server name)".

I've created a small inline aspx page to repro the problem, here it is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html><head>
<script language="CS" runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\temp\export.zip";
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.zip");
        Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
</script>
</head></html>
```

I've tried different things and I noticed that it works again if I comment out the `Response.End` line (but AFAIK this line should be there, at least according to every sample code I find around the web)

Another issue I noticed which may or may not be related is that it will also fail if I remove the `<html>, <head>` and its closing tags.

I've been scratching my head over this for a while now, does anyone have a clue how to get this to work?

Comment: can you please post link of samples you have referred.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Response.End();

try

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

in fact, after .NET 2.0, you should use

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
context.HttpApplication.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Too bad that doesn't allow you to send binary streams.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot (yet) add comments, here comes a small note.

Be aware of **Response.End()** since that method terminates the thread and nothing will be executed after that point.
You may want to do a **Response.Flush()** after **TransmitFile()** to make sure everything gets sent to the client.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) for more information about on Response.End().

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a little late to be useful to the OP, but apparently ZIP files have some problems with MIME types and IIS compression. See the wiki on SharpLibZip:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#wiki-anchorMemory

> Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
>       ' If the browser is receiving a mangled zipfile, IIS Compression may cause this problem. Some members have found that
>       '    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"     has solved this. May be specific to Internet Explorer.

This probably explains why you need to use binary/octet.