# WebMethod to return an html file

Tags: c#, asmx

i am writing a web method to return an html file to android client
here is the code i have tried

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]



public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService

{

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{

    string file = Server.MapPath("index.html");
    return file;

}
}
```

and defiantly its not working, i am not sure about the return type of the method, which to choose.
do i need to convert that html file to string and then return it to client?

Comment: Are you trying to return the *contents* of the file, or the *URL* of the file?

Comment: i need to download the whole html file to the client, which is an android device.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial post returns without doing anything else at the first line:

```
return "Hello World";
```

Remove this line if you want the rest of it to work.

In order to return the contents of the file, just do a [File.ReadAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("index.html");
string content=File.ReadAll(filePath);
return content;
```

**EDIT**:

In order to send a file to the client, you need to send the file's bytes AND set the proper headers. This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239623/download-file-from-webservice-in-asp-net-site). You need to set the content type, content disposition and content length headers. You need to write something like this:

```
var fileBytes=File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Just calling Response.WriteFile isn't enough because you need to set the proper headers

Comment: thanks for reply, but what if i want to return the whole file , not the contents of file ?

Comment: That was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239623/download-file-from-webservice-in-asp-net-site). You need to return a byte array setting the proper headers, so the client will understand you are sending a file as an attachment