# Error in file after download

Tags: asp.net, transmitfile

I have word document which is opening perfectly at server but when i download it using button click event of my website it gets currept.
i am using below code on button click to make document download.
please help to resolve this problem: 
i am using .net framework 3.5

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=StandardLetter" + _responseId.ToString() + ".doc");
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

 Response.TransmitFile (Server.MapPath("~/document/letter/StandardLetter" + _responseId.ToString() + ".doc"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well  here is the code I use, it's vb but easily converted ;)

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(MergedFile)

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & ShortFilename & """")
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length)
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```

This works for PDF and by changing .ContentType to Excel spits that out too.. So I assume this will take any MIME type. Good luck!

I take my pdf document called MergedFile and convert it to a byte(), I give it a 'ShortName' that can be entered by the user. Content-Length is very important..

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `Response.End()` after that code you posted? If not, you will get extra "html" code from the aspx file added to the transmitted file - thus corrupting it.

**EDIT**
As Akshay Anand mentioned, a better way would be to call `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` instead of `Response.End()` [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).

Comment: Kesting: Does Response.Flush() works in place of Response.End()? As Response.End() throws abort exception

Comment: Flush() just sends everything that was cached and continues processing. You need that End() to *stop* that processing. You can ignore that exception - that is the way the processing is aborted

Comment: One issue is whenever such exceptions happen on our web application after a while application becomes very slow and starts spooling. We decided not to use Response.End() due to thread abort, instead used HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Answer (score 1):

Instead try:

```
Response.ContentType ="application/msword";
```

I dont use Word but for Excel I use:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel"
```

Comment: http://www.asptutorial.info/sscript/ContentType.html - here's a list of all of them.