# How to save csv?

Tags: c#, csv

I have a code for getting the csv from datatable . But i can't save the csv formatted file. How can I save ?

```
File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

This is not working?

Comment: What has gone wrong?

Comment: Is sb a CSV formatted text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't u using xls or xlsx instead of csv? 
If you want to use xls or xlsx you can look at nopcommerce opensource projects source code. You can download it from

> http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/downloads/get/598641

And then open the project with

> visual studio **2012**

Go to Nop.Services project under Libraries solution folder. There is a folder in this project named "ExportImport" you can look at the codes.

But if you want csv you can look at following posts

[Write to CSV file and export it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777874/write-to-csv-file-and-export-it)

[How to create CSV Excel file C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422212/simple-c-sharp-csv-excel-export-class)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418520/jquery-c-sharp-export-to-csv

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8411/C-class-library-for-exporting-data-to-CSV-Excel-fi