# LinqtoCsv write - create new or append

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv, io

I'm using LinqToCSV to write a list out to a csv file like this:

```
var outputFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputFile"];
var context = new CsvContext();            
context.Write(cardholders, outputFile, outputDescription);
```

However, whenever this runs, it will overwrite the existing output file. How do I get it to create a new file (if it's not there) or append (if it exists)

Comment: Try this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777874/write-to-csv-file-and-export-it

may be a little helpful

Comment: Try this too. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Comment: I am using LinqtoCSV, not writing my own implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of passing an output file path, pass instead an overload of a [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) which will create a new file if one doesn't exist and append content to one that does:

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputFile"], true)) {
    var context = new CsvContext();
    context.Write(cardholders, writer, outputDescription);
}
```