# Download CSV File by posting JSON data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, download, http-post

In ASP.NET MVC, I am trying to download a file via a post and sending JSON data.  This JSON data are filters for the data being displayed on the page via knockout.js.  The critieria object is always null.  How can I download a file, by sending post data via javascript or a form post?  Ive accomplished an ajax download by using a GET, but now I have extra data, like arrays I need to post.

**Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="@Model.ExportUrl" >
    <input type="hidden" name="criteria" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(data())"  />
    <button class="btn"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Export</button>
</form>
```

**Request**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:2222/members/eventteams/export?eventId=8998
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:128
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:2222
Origin:http://localhost:2222
Referer:http://localhost:2222/members
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
eventId:8998
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
criteria:{"page":1,"pageSize":"100","sortOrder":"Team.Name","sortDirection":"ASC"}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Export(int eventId, DivisionTeamsTableCriteria criteria)
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using knockout.js I created this custom binding that works quite well.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.download = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                id = 'download-iframe-container',
                iframe;

            $(element).unbind('click').bind('click', function () {

                iframe = document.getElementById(id);

                if (!iframe) {
                    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                    iframe.id = id;
                    iframe.style.display = "none";
                }

                if (value.data) {
                    iframe.src = value.url + (value.url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + $.param(ko.mapping.toJS(value.data));
                } else {
                    iframe.src = value.url;
                }

                document.body.appendChild(iframe);

                return false;
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try posting the form to Iframe like this one
[How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

And on the iframe asp.net page, you write the File to response like this
[Write to CSV file and export it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777874/write-to-csv-file-and-export-it)

- Iframe can be 1x1 pixels

Comment: Interesting but I dont think that would get around the JSON issue.

Comment: Which JSON issue? parsing JSON on Code behind?

Comment: Notice I am sending raw json as a parameter at the bottom of the request I pasted above.