# Possible to throw a 404 error within an ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net, http, exception

I was wondering if it's possible to throw a 404 error from within a page(code behind)? Or possibly even throw any other type of error page such as 408(timeout) or 401(authentication required)?

Note: I don't just want to have the page return a status code of 404, I want it to use the ASP.Net(or my CustomErrors) 404 error page.

Something like this in the code behind:

```
if(id>10){ //if id is greater than 10, then it doesn't exist here
  throw 404Error();
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could throw an [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) and set the corresponding status code:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
```

It will also work with other status codes. Just a remark about the 401: as you probably know when ASP.NET MVC detects this code it automatically redirects you to the login page and getting a custom error page for the 401 status code could be a real PITA to implement.

Comment: Hmm. If this exception was thrown when CustomErrors is off, will it show the standard ASP.Net exception page with a stacktrace?

Comment: @Earlz, if `customErrors="Off"` you will probably get an YSOD.

Comment: I was just curious for when in a development environment.  That seems to work though!

Comment: The exception thrown in this way is not transferred to the client. Is a server exception like any other exceptions

Answer (score 25):

A much better way is:

```cs
// Throws a 404 Not found
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.End();
```

There is no need to throw an exception and the above works much better when using custom error pages in the `Web.Config`

Comment: You can also use the enums as well in System.Net.HttpStatusCode.

Comment: `Response.End()` should be avoided as it's a carry-over from Classic ASP. It raises a `ThreadAbortException` which does not play nice in heavy-load environments. Instead call `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` and if necessary, set `Response.SuppressContent = true` after writing an error message.

Comment: This answer is especially helpful because is puts the code fragment into context by including the Clear() and End() calls.

Comment: If you're in `Page_Load` (or any pre-rendering code) You don't have to `Clear()` and `End()` - it will render the page and just set the 404 status on the response properly (if that's what you want).  `Response.End()` is actually kind of bad. There's an excellent explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917180/396005

Answer (score 3):

In regards of Page Load in ASP.NET WebForms needs some small workaround.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpNotFound();
}

private void HttpNotFound()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your client is capable of hitting the PHP page so code is executed, it means that you didn't get a 404 (client side error, "path/file not found"), nor did you get any other sort of 400-class error, BUT you are instead actually getting what should be classified as a 500 error of some sort.

The HTTP spec uses file/path as synonyms.  This comes from the old days of the internet when it was super common for webservers to expose directory browsing lists.