# MIME type question for .XLSX

Tags: vb.net

I have the following block of code: Modified to resolve my Issue

```
'This code is in PAge_load
   Try
            fileSrc = getFileInformation(fileID)
            If fileSrc = "" Then
                Response.Write("No File Information Returned for File ID: " + fileID)
            ElseIf fileSrc = "NoAccess" Then
                Response.Write("You do not have access to this file")
            Else
                If InStr(fileSrc, "src=") > 0 Or InStr(fileSrc, "SRC=") > 0 Then
                    fileLoc = parseString(fileSrc)
                    fileSrc = fileLoc
                End If
                Response.Clear()
                contentType = getContentType(fileSrc)
                Response.ContentType = contentType
                If contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" Or contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" Then
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=StreamFile" + "." + Label1.Text)
                End If
                Response.WriteFile(fileSrc)
                'Response.End() Commented out to prevent Thread Abort Exceptions being thrown.
                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.GetType.ToString.ToLower = "system.threading.threadabortexception" Then

            Else : Response.Write("An Error Occurred During Data Retrieval")

            End If
        End Try
    Else
        Response.Write("An Error Occurred During Data Retrieval")
    End If
    Response.End()    'added back into the code outside of the Try/Catch
```

The proper MIME type is chosen when it has the extension of .xlsx
But when I try to click on the associated hyperlink to the .xlsx spreadsheet I get an error message

[image]

I'm not sure why this occurs or how to resolve this issue. If I am using Response.WriteFile(fileSrc) to resolve this URL could that be the issue?? I have looked at our MIME types on IIS 6.0 and this MIME type exist on IIS.

Comment: Do you have a `Response.Clear` in there? I can see that `PK` is returned which is the beginning of an Office 2007 document, it just looks like something's coming before it or that your MIME type isn't being sent correctly.

Comment: @Chris Haas I do not have a Response.Clear() in my code. I have the following: Response.ContentType = contentType, Response.WriteFile(fileSrc), Response.End(). The current MIME type I am using for the .xlsx files is: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" I do not have 2007 on my machine but I do have the service pack that allows me to open these types of documents,

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the MIME type to the server so it can be served as the MIME type. Simply declaring in your code is not enough if the server cannot handle the MIME type.

By server, I assume IIS. If you are using the built in web development server, you would have to Google MIME types and see if it is even possible to add extras (Assume so, but have never done it).

Comment: @Gregory A Beamer I have added the MIME Types to IIS as well as referenced it in the code. The Content Type is recognized as .xlsx in the "Select Case" code above but when the Response.WriteFile(fileSrc) occurs the error gets thrown (which is the Image above)

Comment: @ErinPackard: I would have to play with XSLX a bit to see if WriteFile() is the issue. The x forms (DOCX, XSLX, PPTX, etc) are actually zip files (change extension to zip and open to see), so it is possible they have to be written using some type of binary writer. I will try to jump back on this after work (2 hours).

Comment: @Gregory A Beamer I have tried both the Response.WriteFile(fileSrc) and the Response.TransmitFile(fileSrc). I get the same results for both approaches.

Comment: Also...Can someone explain what the +2 in this line of code is doing? contentType = Mid(fileSrc, fileSrc.LastIndexOf(".") + 2, 4). I Understand the Mid Function and I understand the LastIndexOf function but I am not certain what the +2 does? I know the ", 4)" is grabbing (up to) the next 4 characters.

Comment: @Erin Packard, `MID` is one-based, not zero,  so `LastIndexOf` finds the period, then add one for the extension and then add one more for converting from one-based to zero-based.

Comment: @Chris Haas Thanks for explaining that one to me...I just didn't get it...It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Response.Clear()` before you start writing binary data to the stream as well as `Response.End()` when you are done. The former clears anything that might already be in the pipeline and the latter stops further writing that may continue.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("Test.xlsx"))
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I see the problem in your updated code. You've got all of this wrapped in a `Try/Catch` which sounds good until you dig into [`Response.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) and find out that it causes a `ThreadAbortException`. This means that even when sucessful your `Catch` block will get called.

You can either just remove the `Try/Catch` block or try using [`Response.CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx)`instead.

If you want to read more on this check out these posts:

- [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful/3917180#3917180)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx

Comment: I added the code to my program for the Response.Clear() and it didn't fix the error message I was recieving (see Image above). I tried to hard code the values into my program to see if that would fix the issue but it fails within a Try/Catch block. I removed the Try/Catch to see if I could catch a better error message for whats going on my program doesn't like the Server.MapPath to my file. I removed that and still doesn't work. I will continue to try to resolve this issue. Any other ideas? We recently had some Microsoft Updates perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: @Erin Packard, did you also add the `Response.End()`? I try to always use `Server.MapPath()` but I think that's because I got in the habit from the old days, don't worry about that part if you don't want to.

Comment: I have added some code to my question. The code is in my Page_Load. Maybe this code will shed some light on my issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this and helping me out. The program does not work with xlsx files unless the Response.End() is in the code. I moved this code outside of the Try/Catch and below the last End If in my code to alleviate the Thread Abort Exceptions being thrown. I also added a line of code that finally allowed for this to work and open .xlsx and .docx documents via my program. Please take a look at the new code above.