# Responding with a csv file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, csv, response

I am trying to make a csv file from a textbox and then send it to the user. This is my code so far:

```
Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", DateTime.Now));

            Response.Write(TextBox_Data.Text);
            Context.Response.End();
```

What is sent is an empty xml file, I have never tried responding with a  file before and I'm wondering why it does this?

I have also tried the following which did not work:

```
var writer = File.CreateText("C:\\file.csv");
            writer.WriteLine(TextBox_Data.Text);

            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now + ".csv");
            Context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Context.Response.Write("C:\\file.csv");
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.End();
```

Let me know if you have the answer :)

Comment: You are trying to create a CSV file from what a user puts in a text box, and then email it to the user, or have the user automatically download it?  Can you give us a little more context for the how and why beyond this code?

Comment: Try writing to  a different path. Perhaps to your profile path. Writing to your root is dangerous.

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to make a downloadable CSV file from a multiline textbox :) Actually I don't care about putting the file on my drive, I just want a downloadable CSV file, with the text from the textbox.

Comment: Writing to the root is not only dangerous, but unless you have explicitly given permission to your app pool identity to do so, it will fail for security reasons

Comment: Another sidenote is that the tostring() of datetime creates a string with a space. The space makes the file lose it's type (also loses the hours and minutes of the datetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code worked for me.  You may just be missing a file extension.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", DateTime.Now));
Response.Write(TextBox_Data.Text);
Context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Keep in mind this code will not take care of things like escape characters but I assume that's what you're expecting.

Comment: ahh... I wrote the extension like this ("attachment; filename={0}", DateTime.Now+".csv"));

This works perfectly from my home pc, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just a complement on joshb's answer regarding the use of Response.End():

MSDN does [not recommend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) the use of `Response.End()` for non-error cases, and in some cases it can actually cause the client to lose some data .

In my case sometimes the downloaded csv would loose the last bytes of the last line, so I removed the `Response.End()` and used

```
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

instead, and I had to override the page's `Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)` method to not write anything on the request, since the csv was already writen.

```
public class PageBase : Page
{
    private bool performRegularPageRender = true;

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (performRegularPageRender)
            base.Render(writer);
    }

    public void SkipRegularPageRendering()
    {
        performRegularPageRender = false;
    }
}
```

More info / credits: 
[msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx);  [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful/3917180#3917180); [PostBack and Render Solutions? Overrides](http://web.archive.org/web/20101224113858/http://www.c6software.com/codesolutions/dotnet/threadabortexception.aspx)