# Export string to CSV not working

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to download a string into CSV file with the following code:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Test.csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("my,csv,file,contents");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

My Fiddler capture gave me the following:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
 Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 22:06:19 GMT
 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 content-disposition: attachment; filename=Test.csv
 Pragma: public
 Cache-Control: private
 Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 20
 Connection: Close

 my,csv,file,contents
```

But, the browser is not downloading any CSV file.
Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an exception: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Found a useful article [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221536/1918553)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The header should be written as `Content-Disposition` - note the capital letters in the name. For more information, search for `19.5.1 Content-Disposition` in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

For example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Also note the double quotes around the file name.

[Responding with a csv file in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417535/responding-with-a-csv-file-in-asp-net)

Comment: The issue was not this. I have found the answer and have posted it. Thanks for your response.