# Alternative to Response.End()?

Tags: asp.net

I handle a request begin_request. At the moment i use Response.End() to stop asp.net from doing whatever else. Response.End() throws an exception is there a non exception way i can end the request?

If your wondering why i have no file its bc i tell nginx what file to serve via http response header thus i have nothing else to do in asp.net. Response.End throws an exception which has to collect stack info and all of that. I obviously dont need that and from my past questions i know throwing exceptions are expensive. So how what can i do where?

Comment: @Oded dunno but its documented on msdn and really doesnt matter

Comment: @Oded: It's a `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`HttpResponse.End()` throws an exception by design; it has to to work.

Only when the `ThreadAbortException` is thrown, does the thread that's rendering the response end. If there's no exception, the response doesn't end.

One alternative would be to call `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` instead. This will prevent further code from executing by jumping straight to the `Application_EndRequest` event.

Comment: Yes so how do i not get the exception? I saw your answer before the edit and i dont see an overload in msdn nor autocomplete http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @acidzombie24: You're right, that's why I edited. The method that has the overload is `Response.Redirect()`, which takes a second boolean parameter that says whether it calls `Response.End()` internally or not.

Answer (score 12):

> call the **HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()**
>   method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the
>   Application_EndRequest event

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629