# want alternative of Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to delete file after download file.My code is

```
private void DownloadZipFileDialogue(string strZipFilePath)
{
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +   Path.GetFileName(strZipFilePath));
  Response.TransmitFile(strZipFilePath);
  Response.End();
  //File.Delete(strZipFilePath);
 }
```

I know after `Response.End();` no code block is execute.If i try to delete file befor `Response.End();` zip file is corrupted.I search every where.I try:
`ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`
insteadof
`Response.End();`.
But i get same result.zip file is corrupted.I see this [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) but unable to find solution.Any idea to solve the problem.Thanks.

Comment: You can run a timer that after 1 second delete the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
private void DownloadZipFileDialogue(string strZipFilePath)
{
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +   Path.GetFileName(strZipFilePath));

    using(Stream input = File.OpenRead(strZipFilePath)){

       /// .NET 4.0, use following line if its .NET 4 project
       input.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);

       /// .NET 2.0, use following lines if its .NET 2 project
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int count = input.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
       while(count > 0){
          Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer,0,count);
          count = input.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
       }
    }

    File.Delete(strZipFilePath);
}
```

Comment: make it little bit clear.How i use it instead of my method.Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting:FIle is damaged and could not be open error message. Please help.