# How to invoke a function but don't wait to finish - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, cron

I got one page where i do some file manipulation, and when file is done, i need to upload to amazon s3. Sometimes file can be large, so user on submit need to wait too much. How can i make something like

1. File manipulation
2. When is done, i send file name parameters  to some function
3. I don't need to wait for that function, i want to use Response.Redirect before uploading is done.

Comment: you can use ajax asynch uploader control for that but cant redirect upto upload is finish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to do this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(YourUploadMethod);
```

There is some comment below arguing with this, so I wrote this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(YourUploadMethod);

        Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
    }

    public void YourUploadMethod(object state)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(7000);
    }// breakpoint: I was redirected to google and then debugger stopped me here
```

Comment: I don't think this method will work for asp.net, because once the main thread finishes, the background threads die as well (regardless if they are finished or not).

Comment: I think Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer will only abort main thread. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the method on a different thread - since you don't have to wait for the function to return, you don't need a callback.

See the [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class and the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class.