# 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in ASP.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have the below code in my ASP.net page:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404
Response.Write(strResult)
Response.End()
```

The code above throws "An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred and was caught."

Can anyone tell me the reason why? And do I solve this.

thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful and the KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Response.End()` from any child object of the page will most likely cause the 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' exception.

Please read [this](http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/handling-threadabortexception-with.html) for a full explaination of why this is happening and methods to avoid/deal with the exception.