# 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' on ASP.NET page compile error

Tags: asp.net

I am working with a ASP.NET 4.0 web application that has a pre-compiled portion, along with user controls that represent individual modules (think CMS).  Running VS 2015 or 2013.  On Windows 8.1, if my user control failed to build at run-time my development environment would exhibit typical behavior, which is a build exception, VS would break, give me the line number, I would fix the problem and move on, the application would continue to run.

Under Windows 10 the application runs ok.  But if I have a build error, anything as simple as a typo in a control ID name, I get a 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in unknown module, with no additional information. Application stops running.  Any thoughts?

Setting and hitting a breakpoint also causes this behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714341/system-threading-threadabortexception-in-asp-net-page

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is not the issue.  Happens before the page runs.