# TransmitFile missing single byte off end of file

Tags: c#, asp.net, transmitfile

Passed parameters are:

```
`C:\Licenses\testfolder\PERSONAL-Wednesday 04 July-0405.txt`,`c2license.txt`
```

And the function is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts serving the download
/// </summary>
public static void InitStoreDownload(string filePath, string serveFileName)
{
    // Get size of file
    var f = new FileInfo(filePath);

    var fileSize = f.Length;
    var extension = f.Extension;

    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Buffer = false;

    // Correct mime type
    if (extension.Equals(".zip", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    else if (extension.Equals(".txt", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    }

    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + serveFileName);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());
    context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    context.Response.Close();

    context.Response.End();
}
```

The `C:\Licenses\testfolder\PERSONAL-Wednesday 04 July-0405.txt` file on the server is 475 bytes long.

The file downloaded when fetched with this script is 474 bytes, missing a single byte off the end of the file.  (The last byte is a full stop, present on the file on the server but not present when downloaded through this function).  This causes the file to become invalid.

We're scratching our heads trying to work out why a byte is missing, could anyone help?

Comment: What happen if you don't explicitly set any `Content-Length` header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

instead of

```
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

Or as other mentioned:

call `Flush()` before `Close()`

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

or omit the call of `Close()` and call `End()` directly cause it includes flushing the Response.

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

There´s a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) about Response.End() maybe it contains useful information for you.

Comment: Still serves 474 bytes, not 475.

Comment: @TomGullen - Try `Response.Flush()` before you call `Close()` and `End()`

Comment: `Flush` and `CompleteRequest` seem to be the winning combo, thanks guys!  Anyone know why this includes the last byte when before it doesn't?

Comment: Because `Response.Close` just nukes the connection before the output buffer got a chance to finish emptying. Ironically if you had just called `Response.End` on its own it probably would have worked, as it includes a `Flush`.