# WCF string method that also serves a download with response.write - Only working in IE so far

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, upload, download

I have a WCF contract like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
string Import_CSV();
```

And then the Import_CSV() method successfully accepts a file upload from HttpContext.Current.Request.Files...
The Import_CSV() method returns a string with message of success or the specific error that occurred.

However, if there are multiple errors with the server operation that I perform on the file that was uploaded, then my goal is to generate a csv file and serve it to the user for them to download.

So, I created csv content, and now I want to display it for the user to download.

Setting the Statuscode to (int)HttpStatusCode.OK, I then return an empty string for success, and use response.write to serve the newly generated csv file like this:

```
HttpContext.current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ImportErrors.csv");
HttpContext.current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
HttpContext.current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
foreach (var line in csvLines)
{
    context.Response.Write(line);
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    context.Response.Flush();
}
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

In internet explorer, everything seems to work as planned, but Firefox & Chrome don't seem to know what to do with this data. I have tried setting different http status codes, and different mime types for the content, but I suspect I am headed down the wrong road.

Any suggestions?

I asked a smaller piece of this puzzle recently on stack overflow here: [Limit of 88 bytes on response.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869430/limit-of-88-bytes-on-response-write)

Answer was very helpful, but now my question is regarding WCF, returning both text and file with this service call, and needs to work in more than just IE. Thanks!

---

Headers when used in chrome:

request:

```
POST /services/PTService.svc/Import_CSV HTTP/1.1
Host: inf18
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 565
Origin: http://inf18
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 
Safari/537.11
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykpa0b9lHil712wdL
Accept: */*
Referer: http://inf18/dashboard/ManageRecipient.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=o50tom0nkjfmglumcmrbtlds
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=ImportErrors.csv
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 18:30:37 GMT
```

---

Headers when used in IE: (IE9 Compat. view, IE9 Standards)

request:

```
POST /services/PTService.svc/Import_CSV HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-
ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer: http://inf18/dashboard/ManageRecipient.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
2.0.50727;     .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MDDR)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc180222c0fb0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: inf18
Content-Length: 598
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=e2iwodwyy2muxoj4zhpisl5k
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=ImportErrors.csv
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 18:33:34 GMT
```

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to inspect the request and response when using IE AND Firefox/Safari/Chrome?

Comment: Yes I did try fiddler, I can edit the question here in a sec to show those as well incase that helps

Comment: "_Firefox & Chrome don't seem to know what to do with this data_" What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that in those browsers, the response.write is not prompting the save dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to add the following lines before you are writing to the Response?

```
/******************************************/
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
/******************************************/

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ImportErrors.csv");
//rest of your code sample
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it didn't make a difference in the result though

Comment: Actually.. this DID solve my problem, the header was not just text anymore. I didnt know it solved the problem right away though, because for some reason even though the headers were now fixed, the file download didnt get prompted until I chanegd my clientside control.. I was using kendoUI web upload control, and im not sure exactly what it does behind the scenes. After i changed the client control to a regular file upload with a iframe as a landing page, i was able to receive the file as a download, or the error text in my iframe buffer. Thanks again for your help.