# Proper way to skip page execution after Response.RedirectToRoute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, user-experience, response.redirect

I'm writing an asp.net 4.5 application using the new routing features. I have a page that displays some information about an item. In the `Page_Load` event I check the route data (item id) and user permissions, and if something isn't right (e.g. the id is for a deleted item) I use `Response.RedirectToRoute` to send them packing, right back to the home page. Do not pass GO, do not collect $200.

This made perfect sense until I tried to access a deleted item and instead of the home page I got an error page. I did some digging and discovered that even after I use `RedirectToRoute` (unlike the standard `Redirect` method) the rest of the page code [continues to execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783087.aspx), which at the very least seems wasteful (since I'm just going to throw away the results) and throws errors when the necessary data doesn't exist.

I did a little more SO mining and discovered the incredible [*evil*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful/3917180#3917180) that is `Response.End()`. It does what I need, but even the MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) tells me that `Response.End` is the bastard child of an ancient accursed language and isn't fit to see the light of day. The primary objection seems to be the fact that Response.End throws an exception, and that's bad for performance. I'm not the most experienced developer, so I don't understand the issue entirely, but I have trouble believing that throwing an exception is more expensive than loading the entire web page. The [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917180/1812515) seem rather complex and excessive for a task so simple, especially since most pages require some kind of validity check.

What am I supposed to do in this situation? Use `Response.End` and beg forgiveness for my insolence? Cobble together some ugly workaround? Or is my perspective on the problem all wrong to begin with? I'd really like to know.

Update: Now that I've thought it over a bit more, I wonder if I do have the wrong perspective on the problem. Perhaps an immediate redirect is the not the best response for the user experience. Would I be better off wrapping all the controls in a panel, and using something like this?

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    'Validation Code
    If notValid Then
        ControlsPanel.Visible = false
        ErrorPanel.Visible = true
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be going out on a limb by not answering the question directly, but I liked seeing your update regarding user experience.  I prefer your suggested approach.

I like to give a 410 error for id's that are not valid and extend it a bit with (translated from C#):

```
Protected Sub ItemDoesNotExist()
'item does not exist, serve up error page
ControlsPanel.Visible = False
ErrorPanel.Visible = True

'add meta tags for noindex
Dim mymeta As New HtmlMeta()
mymeta.Name = "robots"
mymeta.Content = "noindex"
Page.Header.Controls.Add(mymeta)

'RESPOND WITH A 410
Response.StatusCode = 410
Response.Status = "410 Gone"
Response.StatusDescription = "Gone"
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
'important for IIS7, otherwise the Custom error page for 404 shows.
Page.Title = "item gone"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I didn't realize that you could respond with an error code and still load the page. I will definitely keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 10):

[RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783087.aspx) is actually wraps [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) passing `false` for ending the request - hence, the request continues. You can use [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) as immediate call to terminate the request so that next application events would not be invoked.

`Response.End` (and other Redirect variation) throws `ThreadAbortException` to abort the request processing thread which is really a *bad* way to stop request processing. In .NET world, exception processing is always considered expensive because CLR then needs to search up the stack all the way up for exception processing blocks, create stack trace etc. IMO, `CompleteRequest` was introduced in .NET 1.1 to avoid the same which actually relies on setting flag in ASP.NET infrastructure code to skip further processing except `EndRequest` event.

Yet another (and better) way is to use [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) and avoid client round-trip for setting redirect all together. Only issue is that client would not see the redirected URL in the browser address bar. I typically prefer this method.

**EDIT**
`CompleteRequest` wouldn't never work in page case where subsequent page events would be still invoked because page being a handler, all its events happens within a single (and current) application event `ProcessRequest`. So only way seems to be setting a flag and check that flag in overrides such as `Render`, `PreRender`, `RaisePostBackEvent` etc.

From maintenance perspective, it make sense to have such functionality in base page class (i.e. maintaining the flag, offering `CompleteRequest` method to subclasses and overriding life cycle event methods). For example,

```
internal class PageBase: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool _requestCompleted;

    protected void CompleteRequest()
    {
       Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
       _requestCompleted = true;
    }

    protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl,
    string eventArgument)
    {
       if (_requestCompleted) return;
       base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
    }

    protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
       if (_requestCompleted) return;
       base.Render(writer);   
    }

    protected internal override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
       if (_requestCompleted) return;
       base.OnPreRender(e);   
    }

    ... and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that `CompleteRequest` was proposed as a better option, but it also continues to execute all the code on the page. Various controls on the page get their data from the item and when it doesn't exist they throw errors, so I get an error page rather than a redirect. I could go through and check for validity on every method, but that seems _rather_ unnecessary and less maintainable.

Comment: I find it interesting that you mention `Server.Transfer`. While I appreciate the benefit of avoiding a round-trip, I don't feel like that method would work well for my purposes, as the user's current URL is invalid. I've also read that `Server.Transfer` calls `Response.End` and I don't see an overload of the function to avoid this.

Comment: @probackpacker, please accept my apology! `CompleteRequest` affects application pipeline events, but current handler event would go on. There would be no other way but using flag to check within page - from maintenance perspective, you can extract that into a reusable base page class (see my edit).

Comment: @probackpacker, "return" or "return 0", after CompleteRequest, will prevent the current event handler from going on.

Comment: I use `context.Response.Redirect` in ***IHttpHandler***. Code: `[WebService(Namespace = "http://portalxxx")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class ssoToExternalApp : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)`