# Get rid of ThreadAbortException with httpResponse.End

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Does anyone know of a way to replace `httpResponse.End()` with something that does not throw a `ThreadAbortException` causing issues with performance? Someone suggested doing a 'HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()', but this doesn't do everything `httpResponse.End()` does, like sending buffered data to the client which is a problem for me.

Comment: Do you have any indication that the exception is *really* causing an issue with performance? How many times is it being thrown every second, and how CPU-bound is your server?

Comment: I am not sure, but the QA team at my company seems to believe so.

Comment: Your QA team should provide *evidence* of this then. (Exceptions aren't hugely cheap, but equally unless you're processing tens of thousands of requests per second on a single machine, I'd expect them to get lost in the noise.)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I doubt that this is *really* causing significant problems. However, it's not generally a great idea anyway... it's an abuse of exceptions, really. (IMO, anyway.)

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx):

> This method is provided only for compatibility with ASP—that is, for compatibility with COM-based Web-programming technology that preceded ASP.NET. If you want to jump ahead to the EndRequest event and send a response to the client, call [`CompleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) instead.

Obviously the current method will still continue after you call `CompleteRequest`, so you'll need to make sure you complete the handling of the current event cleanly.

Comment: One can also EndRequest without exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful). If you scroll down to the answer by 'Jay Zalos'. I replaced `httpResponse.End()` with the following 3 lines:

```
Response.Flush()
Response.SuppressContent = True
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. The fact that you need SuppressContent indicates that some strange things are happening (generating content that is never sent...). Also Flush is a perf problem (even if executed only once per request). Please do not mark this as the answer. It will mislead future visitors to think this is best practice.