# Response.End() and CompleteRequest()

Tags: c#, request, response

What are the advantage and disadvantage for each of `Response.End()` and `CompleteRequest()`? Where should I and should I not use them? I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) but I didn't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`HttpResponse.End` flushes the output buffer to the client and terminates the current request-handling thread (this is bad), whereas `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest` tells ASP.NET to immediately skip all future stages in the ASP.NET pipeline and jump directly to the EndRequest step (which also raises the `HttpApplication.EndRequest` event). The request thread then proceeds with normal end-of-life cleanup.

So, `Response.End` is like an ejector seat: it quickly ends things, but means you lose control and might be unnecessarily harsh. Whereas `CompleteRequest` is like making an emergency landing at the nearest airport.

Comment: So when I must use Response.End() and When I must use HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()

Comment: Ideally, you'd never need to use either.

Comment: Read [Correct use of System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) - `Response.End` is a risky "ejector seat" ... use with **utmost** caution...

Comment: That's exactly what I need, an ejector seat, but I can't find that method anywhere

Comment: @nuander are you using WebAPI, ASP.NET Core or MVC 6? They radically changed the ASP.NET API in those releases.

Comment: Can I assume then it's also a bad idea to call either one when writing your own iHttpHandler?

Comment: @Dai If the use of HttpApplication.CompleteRequest is not recommended, then how to do proper redirection ? Isn't the Response.Redirect(url, false); followed by Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); proper way ?

Comment: @JayShah In the context of a Redirection-response, using `CompleteRequest` _might_ be correct - provided that you don't have any other code in the request pipeline that needs to run. That said (and without knowing more about your use-case) I wouldn't necessarily recommend using `CompleteRequest`, especially in a WebForms `.aspx` `Page` handler, where some view cleanup and session-management code probably should be run instead of skipped-over. FWIW (and as far as I can remember) I've never _needed_ to use `CompleteRequest` with `Response.Redirect` in ASP.NET 4.x.