# Cost of using Response.End()

Tags: c#, response, threadabortexception

I'm using the following code to to download files, but I'm face that `Response.End` always causes `Exception`. Is This cost for my application behavior? if yes how can get an alternative way to download files. I tried to use `Thread.ResetAbort()` to handle the exception but this result unwanted additional data to be added to the file

```
try
            {
                   DownloadFiles();                       
                   Response.End();                   
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
               // Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
            catch (GSException ex)
            {
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                hdnResult.Value = ex.Message;
                // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "checkDownloadError", "window.parent.checkDownloadError('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                hdnResult.Value = "Oops! Something unexpected happened. Please try again later";
                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "checkDownloadError", "window.parent.checkDownloadError('Oops! Something unexpected happened. Please try again later');", true);
            }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Thread Abort Exception !

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay the *exception throw cost* that comes with `Response.End` you could use the [`Application.CompleteRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) method instead.