# ASP.NET 2.0 FileUpload.PostedFileSaveAs() A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: asp.net, linux, share

I am getting the below error while trying to upload a text file from client machine to a linux shared file. Before the shared file was on a Windows machine, there I did not get the error.

[image]

The annoying issue with the error is: it happens some times and it does not happen other time. So cannot reproduce it.

Now, is there any thing ( specially) I need to check if a linux folder is used with ASP.NET 2.0

Edit 1: 
The below details from debugger:

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled by user code
>     Message="A device attached to the system is not functioning.\r\n"
>     Source="mscorlib"
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>          at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename)
>          at LoadFile.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in r:\TimeCard\LoadFile.aspx.cs:line 138
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Edit 2:
I'm using the below code

```
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(mAttachFileName);
```

where mAttachFileName will be \\LinuxShare\Share\Emp\123.txt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754821/thread-was-being-aborted-after-response-redirectdefault-aspx/31755148#31755148

Comment: @IrishChieftain, I don't have Response.Redirect in the event. I have tested the code 15 times, and it worked 11 times and failed 4 times.

Comment: Very odd Rauf, can you post the relevant code? I'm thinking it's either a physical error or maybe a permissions issue?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - Added the code.

Comment: Can you show the surrounding, relevant code? Is there a Using statement, etc? This tells us nothing...

Comment: There is no 'using' command. We just prepare the file name and use the function to save to the shared folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143610/discussion-between-rauf-and-irishchieftain).

Comment: I can already see from the error that you're using a PostedFile.SaveAs method call. Check the permissions on the share first. Is it on a different domain, etc?