# Error to force file download C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, download

I have a page with a list where can I download XML Files, but there is a server of a company that below the XML file is the page's HTML together. The XML on download code usually works on all servers where the application is installed except that server. The method for downloading the file is as follows:

```
 public void StreamFileToBrowser(string sFileName, byte[] fileBytes, string ext)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Buffer = false;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";//string.Format("application/{0}", ext);
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);           
    }
```

Any alternative way to force file download?

**EDIT**

This method is called when the user click on download button.

Comment: I'm having trouble making out the meaning of your first sentence, specifically the part after the comma: "but there is a server of a company that below the XML file is the page's HTML together". Could you either explain this or correct it?

Comment: Sorry with english. Isn't my native language. When I try to download the XML file, the HTML code come below together in the same file.

Comment: Are you the client side, or the server side? The way it looks in the code, you are the server side.

Comment: its heavily depended on the server API. My guess is that you should first make a HTTP request and then save the returned XML

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm the server side using C#.

Comment: @Steve can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem using:

```
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
context.Response.End();
```

at the end.

Answer (score 2):

After you write the file to the output. You should end the response by calling:

```
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

This prevents anything further from being written to the response. Usually this isn't necessary if you separate out your XML download logic into a separate handler. But when you have some logic that does both, you can run into issues.

Comment: Like 

context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
?

Comment: Alternatively, Response.End().

Comment: Also, if the filename might have spaces or commas or anything like that, you should put it in double quotes for the content-disposition header.

Comment: Like that? 
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sFileName + "\"");

Comment: And context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); works like Response.End()? that methods do the same thing?

Comment: @Scbairros Yes, they are similar, but they are not the same. See [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).

Comment: context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); doesn't works for me, but I resolved my problem. Thanks!