# Export html table to Excel file using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to export my string html table to excel. When trying to export and when I click save I get the following exception

> The server can not add the header after sending the HTTP headers

This is my html table :

```
string tab = "<table cellpadding='5' style='border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse'>";
tab += "<tr><td style=' border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>NumClient</td><td style=' border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>Raison Sociale</td></tr>";
tab += "<tr><td style='border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>" + NumClient + "</td><td style='border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>"
+ Rs + "</td><td style='border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;text-align:right;'> </td></tr>";
tab += "</table>";
```

This is Controller code :

```
 Response.ClearContent();   
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Reliquat.csv");
 Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
 Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
 Response.Write(tab);
 Response.End();
```

And when I click continue I get an excel file that contains html code:

```
<table cellpadding='5' style='border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse'>";
tab += "<tr><td style=' border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>NumClient</td><td style=' border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;'>Raison Sociale</td></tr>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: The content type is incorrect. You might want to change it to application/excel and use Reliquat.xslx as file name

Comment: thank you Hatjhie but I got the same error

Comment: Alright. I think the posted reply below would be able to answer your question. You could give it a try.

Comment: Change your code to:
Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Reliquat.xslx");
        Response.Write(tab);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();

Comment: Don't use Response.End() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the codes below. Hopefully, it works.

```
Response.ClearContent(); 
Response.ClearHeaders(); 
Response.BufferOutput = true; 
Response.ContentType = "application/excel"; 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Reliquat.xslx"); 
Response.Write(tab); 
Response.Flush(); 
Response.Close(); 
Response.End();
```

From here:
http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/export-html-excel-asp-net/

Comment: This is Web Forms sample but you can change it to work with MVC

Comment: Thanks Jernej , but I don't understand webForms very well ,Have you an example with MVC ? :)

Comment: when I tried the code bellow , I got the following exception :
Remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.

Comment: I got the first exception : The server can not add the header after sending the HTTP headers

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() but I did'nt understand why

Comment: Presume you incorrectly mentioned "Reliquat.xslx" whilst the correct one is Reliquat.xlsx / xls