# Replace Response.End with ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you safely replace `Response.End` with `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`?

Do you need to `Response.Flush` first to get the same behavior or will it flush automatically?

**EDIT**: From here: ([Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)) it looks like you should flush first and that `End` internally invokes `CompleteRequest`, but it also does say that it skips steps in the pipeline, does this mean the behavior is actually different even if I flush?

Comment: I'm hovering over the dupe-hammer on this. I believe that this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful and that it contains everything you need to answer your 2 questions (including the source of `Response.End`, which implies that by calling `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` directly, you'll be skipping a `Flush`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)

Comment: @spender thanks, I'll have a read, haven't seen that one before, other threads don't talk about flush.