# Throwing System out of memory exception for certain values of timestamps

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have a website in ASP.net using Vb.net as code behind it is throwing errors for certain values of timestamps when I am trying to retrieve data in a grid view. What could be the problem? The error is System out of memory the website is hosted on a server which is IIS.

My code behind is as follows:

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public dad As OleDbDataAdapter

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Protected Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

End Sub


Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim connectionString As [String] = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data" + " Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\GL Communications Inc\DataImport\VQT.mdb"
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(AVG(POLQA_Score),3) AS mean_POLQA_score FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND VQuad_PhoneID =?", conn)

    Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(Stdev(POLQA_score),3) AS stdev_POLQA_score FROM VQTPOLQA WHERE VQT_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  VQuad_PhoneID=?", conn)

    Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(AVG(RTD),3) AS mean_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND RTD>0 AND  VQuad_PhoneID=?", conn)

    Dim cmd4 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ROUND(Stdev(RTD),3) AS STDEV_RTD FROM VQuadData WHERE VQuad_Timestamp BETWEEN ? AND? AND RTD>0 AND VQuad_PhoneID=?", conn)


    Dim param As OleDbParameter
    param = cmd.CreateParameter
    param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    param.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

    Dim param1 As OleDbParameter
    param1 = cmd.CreateParameter
    param1.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param1.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    param1.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

    GridView1.DataBind()

    Dim param2 As OleDbParameter
    param2 = cmd2.CreateParameter
    param2.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param2.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    param2.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(param2)

    Dim param3 As OleDbParameter
    param3 = cmd2.CreateParameter
    param3.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param3.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    param3.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(param3)

    GridView2.DataBind()

    Dim param4 As OleDbParameter
    param4 = cmd3.CreateParameter
    param4.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param4.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    param4.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(param4)

    Dim param5 As OleDbParameter
    param5 = cmd3.CreateParameter
    param5.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param5.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    param5.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
    cmd3.Parameters.Add(param5)

    GridView3.DataBind()


    Dim param6 As OleDbParameter
    param6 = cmd4.CreateParameter
    param6.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param6.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    param6.ParameterName = "@StartDate"
    cmd4.Parameters.Add(param6)

    Dim param7 As OleDbParameter
    param7 = cmd4.CreateParameter
    param7.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date
    param7.Value = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    param7.ParameterName = "@EndDate"
    cmd4.Parameters.Add(param7)



    GridView4.DataBind()


    conn.Close()

End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub ClearControls(ByVal control As Control)
    For i As Integer = control.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ClearControls(control.Controls(i))
    Next
    If Not (TypeOf control Is TableCell) Then
        If control.[GetType]().GetProperty("SelectedItem") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim literal As New LiteralControl()
            control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal)
            Try
                literal.Text = DirectCast(control.[GetType]().GetProperty("SelectedItem").GetValue(control, Nothing), String)
            Catch
            End Try
            control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control)
        ElseIf control.[GetType]().GetProperty("Text") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim literal As New LiteralControl()
            control.Parent.Controls.Add(literal)
            literal.Text = DirectCast(control.[GetType]().GetProperty("Text").GetValue(control, Nothing), String)
            control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control)
        End If
    End If
    Return
End Sub

Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable("GridView_Data")
    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView5.HeaderRow.Cells
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text)
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView5.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = row.Cells(i).Text
        Next
    Next
    Dim wb As New XLWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewPOLQA.xlsx")
    Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.[End]()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
    Return
End Sub


Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable("GridView_Data")
    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView6.HeaderRow.Cells
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text)
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView6.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = row.Cells(i).Text
        Next
    Next
    Dim wb As New XLWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewRTD.xlsx")
    Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.[End]()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ExportToExcel(data As IEnumerable(Of Dynamic), sheetName As String)
    Dim wb As New XLWorkbook()
    Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)
    ws.Cell(2, 1).InsertTable(data)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", [String].Format("attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", sheetName.Replace(" ", "_")))

    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        wb.SaveAs(memoryStream)
        memoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
        memoryStream.Close()
    End Using

    HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

This is error stack trace I am getting as mentioned below.

```
[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Convert.ToBase64String(Byte[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length, Base64FormattingOptions options) +119
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +229
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Serialize(Object state, Purpose purpose) +13
   System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +40
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save() +106
   System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object state) +108
   System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() +653
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5314
```

The web.config file is as follows:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>


<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ConnectionString2" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ConnectionString3" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ConnectionString4" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ConnectionString5" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ConnectionString6" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\VQT_GL Testing.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="VQTConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\GL Communications Inc\DataImport\VQT.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <authentication mode="None"/>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
      <machineKey
validationKey="62AFB48AEFD48352027301E7D1E6180E95AFF287377B03FA4492404998D3C1ADD2EBB9C8D18DD4A87E53759167ADC385AE29CC3B0F12965B4D68A4964D0F8062"
decryptionKey="A4E89B2AA3F120979F154A5EFCF4F4254A1925B59285A2A9"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
/>
    </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!--The default size is 30000000 bytes (28.6 MB). MaxValue is 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)-->
        <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How many rows are you pulling into your GridView?

Comment: @chakeda Its as per custom timestamp values but I am displaying only a single value on gridview so it is one row

Comment: What Excel library are you using? Have you tried closing the workbook when you're done with it?

Comment: @JohnWu Excel I am using  ClosedXML.Excel but the site itself is crashing for longer duration of time stamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ClosedXML, `XLWorkbook` is disposable, so you should be using it within a [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) block. If you don't do this, the workbook objects will keep on sucking up memory and give you random OutOfMemoryExceptions eventually. My guess is that the relationship to the timestamp value is coincidence.

```
Using wb As New XLWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewPOLQA.xlsx")
    wb.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream)
    Response.Flush()
End Using
```

Also, [do not use Response.End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).

Also, I got rid of the MemoryStream. You can write directly to the OutputStream.

Comment: Now it is giving this error stack trace 
[CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.]

Comment: You should start another question, with the stack trace and other essential troubleshooting information.

Answer (score 1):

When you run cmd prompt as an administrator on the server one must use `iisreset/ stop` and `iisreset/ start` command to refresh memory usage.