# HttpResponse not writing all the bytes in the downloaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, .net-4.5, httpresponse

Thank You for reading my post. I have written a HttpResponse code to download a file. Following the code:

```
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(appPath, randomFileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, data);

            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.BufferOutput = true;
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            response.CacheControl = "private";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            response.Flush();
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
```

Here, the `File.WriteAllBytes` method creates a file in the server, this is an xlsx file. Upon opening this file in notepad++, the file has 1506791 characters. When opening the downloaded xlsx file in notepad++ the file has 1490407 characters.

The downloaded file doesnot open in Microsoft Excel. I used notepad++ to see if all the bytes were downloaded or not. Apparently, all the bytes are not downloaded.

HttpResponse is not downloading all the bytes.

Is it possible that the `data.Length` method does not count unicode chars and when `response.BinaryWrite` is executed, the `binarywrite` does and stops when `data.Length` value reached which is not the end of the byte.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what the value of `data.Length` is?

Comment: A little hard to keep track with  all those Clear() and Flush() calls.

Comment: @itsme86 The `data.Length` is as same as the length of the file written by `File.WriteAllBytes`. `data.Length` returns correct value.

Comment: Have you tried replacing "attachment" with "inline" in your Content-Disposition header?  e.g. - response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\";");

Comment: [Avoid using `Response.End()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the file you save right before sending the same data back to the client (let me know how it goes):

```
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(appPath, randomFileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, data);

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + randomFileName);
        response.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
        response.WriteFile(fullPath);
```

Comment: Thank You but when I used this code with `response.Flush()` at the end, the file didn't download and the message was `Failed Network`

Comment: Have you tried it just as it is above (i.e. - No Flush, End, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it didn't download anything. Then I added flush which tried to download.

Comment: What about with adding only "response.End();" as the last line in my suggestion? (no Flush, etc.);

Comment: When adding `response.End()` after `response.WriteFile(fullPath)`, the download starts but just keeps circling and has message `Starting...`. Does not go past this.