# Saved PDF file is corrupt after download if user visits my asp.net site from email link, but is not corrupt after manual login?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, download

My apologies if I've missed any applicable answers during my search.

My asp.net website sends user A an email with a link. Trustwave adds some wrapper information around the link before delivering the email. The user clicks the link, authenticates, and is taken to applicable content. If user A navigates to docs.aspx, selects a PDF, and downloads, PDF is corrupt when user A opens the PDF. The site doesn't create the PDF, it was uploaded by user B.

**But**, if user A manually browses to site, authenticates, navigates to docs.aspx, and downloads the PDF, it isn't corrupt. Both cases use the same authentication, doc.aspx, code-behind, and PDF.

Stepping through the code is difficult because I don't know how to generate the (Trustwave-protected) email link in my test environment.

Can you suggest additional ways to troubleshoot this? A PNG file worked in both cases, but I don't want to limit the file types user B can upload. The PDF file size is 11 KB, and I'm using an up-to-date Chrome web browser. Simple detailed answers and examples are appreciated.

Here is the doc.aspx method:

```
For Each i As ListItem In Me.FileListbox.Items

    If i.Selected Then
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & i.Text)
        DownloadFile = Server.MapPath("documents") & i.Text

        Select Case Right(i.Text, 3)
            Case "doc"
                Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
            Case "jpg"
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            Case "pdf"
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Case "png"
                Response.ContentType = "image/png"
            Case "xls"
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Case "zip"
                Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
            Case Else
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        End Select

        Response.TransmitFile(DownloadFile)
        Response.End()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this value in DownloadFile the right one?

Comment: Please see [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087777/1115360)

Comment: In `Server.MapPath...` you have an `&` and a `+`.

Comment: @wazz -- that was a syntax error I introduced while editing for clarity (this site was developed in vb.net but I've since switched to c#)

Comment: @the_lotus -- yes, it's the right file. There aren't any duplicated files. I also tested by uploading new files and was able to repeat the error.

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- I will try removing the Response.End()

Comment: @glimmering Also, you should investigate what the corruption is: is it too short, does it have some HTML prepended, are some bytes changed...?

Comment: @glimmering I was asking because Server.MapPath does not return a "\" at the end and if you just concatenate a filename then the DownloadFile value will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the file name in quotes in the header:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + i.Text + "\"")
```

Comment: I will try this, but what is the benefit of doing so?

Comment: In VB.NET, that would be `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & i.Text & """")`.

Comment: @glimmering - I seem to remember it fixing a problem for me a long time ago, thought it might be the fix. Not seeing anything else ATM. (And I think it's *supposed* to be in quotes, IIRC.)

Comment: Also, possibly missing a slash after 'documents' in `Server.MapPath`. ? In my download code, I use (C#): `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/downloads/other-folder/" + fileName));`. Note the slash before the file name.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I have made this change but the problem is still there.

Comment: All - I will post here once I (hopefully!) solve this. Thanks again for your time and suggestions.

Comment: All - here is an example of the same technique, converted to c# for another project. This works with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing witch go wrong:

1-Never close Response when you write or transmit something on them.

Response.End() cause Thread interruption use Response.Flush() instead.
However following code is a better technique to transmit file as binary data and not as a file:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & "put your filename here")
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"  

        'Read your file as binary data from your phisical path on server 
        Dim data() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("put your path of file here .pdf")

        ' And transmit those data as binary 
        Response.BinaryWrite(data)
        Response.Flush()
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()


        'IMPORTANT: NEVER CLOSE Response whith Response.End and use Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I tried this but the problem is still happening.