# ASP.NET - Sending responses in JSON - Response received is impossible, considering the source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http, serialization

My Base Class has the following method defined:

```
protected void RespondWithJson<T>(T graph)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    ClearResponse();
    response.ContentType = "text/json";
    DataContractJsonSerializer ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    ds.WriteObject(response.OutputStream, graph);
    response.End();
    Sql_Disconnect();
}
```

The method belongs to all pages that will respond with JSON, depending on the query parameters in the URL.

The responses that I get from one of my pages makes no sense whatsoever, when you consider the source code involved.

The page is for submitting picks individually for our pick & pack operation.
RespondWithJson is the only method that these pages will use to determine their response.

The only response the picksubmission page makes is of the type PickSubmissionResult

e.g.

```
RespondWithJson(new PickSubmissionResult() { message = "Some URL Parameters are missing from the call!" });
```

However, the response that I actually get from this page is of the type `List<PickingRow>`

A *different* page entirely on the server will make responses with `List<PickingRow>`.

So why is another page's methods being invoked on this page??

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but you should read the answers to [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087777/215552)

Comment: Appreciate the comment - I think I have discovered the actual issue
I think it's because each of my Pages has a method that is subscribed to an event that belongs to a static class.
My understanding was that this static instance would be unique to each request/page - apparently this is not the case. As a result, a previously accessed page's version of this handler is invoked even when visiting a different page.
 - I will have to revise some of my code and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Previously, I had my "Requestor" class set to static.
I have now replaced each Page's reference to this class with a reference to their own individual instance of this class (is now a dynamic class)

```
    protected Requestor requestor;

    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        requestor = new Requestor();
        requestor.SessionSet += Requestor_SessionSet;
    }
```

Now the Requestor_SessionSet handlers are only invoked on the page visited last, instead of all visited pages within the life-cycle of the domain.

The lesson here:

Static instances are not unique to the request/page but are server-wide